# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QuerySet' and 'int'

Tags: python, django

```
models.py :
    class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user_test_point = models.IntegerField(default=0)

views.py :
def test_result(request):
    user_test_point = Profile.objects.values('user_test_point')
    test_word = request.GET['test_word']
    test_mean = request.GET['mean']
    flag = "flag"

    if test_mean == test_word:
        flag = "correct"
        Profile.objects.values('user_test_point').update(user_test_point + 1)
        context = {"flag": flag}

        return render(request, 'test_result.html', context)
    else:
        flag = "wrong"
        context = {"flag": flag}
        context['mean'] = test_mean
        return render(request, 'test_result.html', context)
```

I created user_test_point in `enter code here`models.py. Then, I want to add point 1 if user's answer is correct. I wonder can I modify this code "Profile.objects.values('user_test_point').update(user_test_point + 1)"? I want to know how to fix this error "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QuerySet' and 'int'".
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `user_test_point` (which is not an int) with `1`, add it with `models.IntegerField(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

What you need to do is get the Profile object for that user and increment the `user_test_point` as follows

```
user = request.user
profile_obj = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
profile_obj.user_test_point = profile_obj.user_test_point + 1
profile_obj.save()
```

or something like this

```
user = request.user
profile_obj = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
profile_obj.user_test_point = F('user_test_point') + 1
profile_obj.save()
```